Track events happening within a external website iframe embedded into my website
The website which hosts the iframe is mysite.com. The iframe source is othersite.com. I have code/admin access to both websites.
This is how the iframe added to mysite.com
<iframe src="https://othersite.com" style="position:fixed; top:0; left:0; bottom:0; right:0; width:100%; height:100%;></iframe>

I want them to share the same analytics code and report events happening in them both to a single dashboard.
I have tried inserting analytics code into othersite.com but it does not work.
Adding the analytics code to the header of mysite.com before the iframe tag records page_view but does not record events within the iframe.
Is there a way for the same analytics code to report events within the iframe?

There are many articles on how to track iframes. This one is good: https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/iframe-cross-domain-tracking-in-google-tag-manager/
In short: when an iframe is pulling a page from a different domain, your only option to track actions within it is to load code on that page and issue window messages to the parent. Then your main analytics code will be able to listen to those messages and track them appropriately.
